# Loop a grunt task?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I need to loop through my copy task and output in a different folder each time. How can I loop through it and provide a var to it each time? I have a variety of languages to output and each needs to go in its own folder.

```
copy:{
        files:{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '../',
            src: [
                'static/**',
            ],
            dest: '../../public/[language-folder-var]'
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-iterate?

Comment: grunt-iterate looks good but you have to pass in the array of languages, I want to have this in a config somewhere

Comment: [`grunt.file.readJSON(filepath [, options])`](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.file) and then use that.

Comment: How would you use readJSON and input the vars to grunt-iterate?

Comment: Read the documentation - it's all there.

Comment: Sorry - I don't see how it's all there. I can see how it explains how to read a file but how would these contents be passed to grunt-iterate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your config object, you can use template tags to inject data into strings:

```
copy:{
        files:{
            expand: true,
            cwd: '../',
            src: [
                'static/**',
            ],
            dest: "../../public/<%= grunt.option('lang') %>/"
        }
    }
```

Then you'll need a function that will iterate though the different languages, set the grunt.option variable, and run the task for each:

```
function compileLangFiles() {
    var langs = ['en', 'fr', 'jp'], lang;

    for (lang in langs) {
        grunt.option('lang', lang);
        grunt.task.run('copy');
    }
}

grunt.registerTask('copyLang', copyLangFiles);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your copy task contains a lot of filetype specific handling, one route you can take is to make separate tasks for different file types.
e.g.
`grunt.registerTask( 'build', ['copyjs','copycss'] );`

If you have many filetypes, this wouldn't be advisable. In that case, you should dynamically create the targets (tasks). I would put the paths in an array and forEach loop over it, creating the tasks object within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Panthro, I imagine something like this.

Assuming a config.json like:

```
{ langs: ['en', 'fr', 'de'] }
```

Load it (auto-parsed)

```
grunt.langconfig = grunt.file.readJSON('config.json');
grunt.langs = grunt.langconfig.langs;
```

And in your [iterate task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-iterate) join `langs`

```
argName: grunt.langs.join(',')
```

Comment: Thanks - useful but iterate just won't work! Warning: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Comment: Thanks but I cant even perform the basic example task for iterate, same split of undefined warning, I think it's to do with iterates dependencies not working.

Comment: I don't think you are understanding me. Forget the answer to my question for now. I can't even run the grunt-iterate example, Cannot read property 'split' of undefined. I believe something to do with async not installing.